# R CUT Data Table

Tags: r, cut

I have the following problem when doing a cut on a data.table.
I don't know why it doesn't do the filter by "prod" correctly.
If I run the cut on the outside, as seen below, it does the cut correctly but not inside the data table.
Do you know why and how I can fix it?
Thank you

```
library(data.table)
    db<-data.frame(count=c(331948, 334999, 321000, 305000, 324100, 310000, 305000, 325000, 305000, 329999, 315000,531948, 534999, 521000, 505000, 524100, 510000, 505000, 525000, 505000, 529999, 515000), prod=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"))

head(db)

    count prod
1  331948    a
2  334999    a
3  321000    a
4  305000    a
5  324100    a
6  310000    a

setDT(db)[ , id := cut(count,8,digits=1,dig.lab = 7), by = prod]

    count prod                  id
1: 331948    a   (531249.1,535029]
2: 334999    a   (531249.1,535029]
3: 321000    a (519999.5,523749.4]
4: 305000    a   (504970,508749.9]
5: 324100    a (523749.4,527499.2]
6: 310000    a (508749.9,512499.8]

table(db[db$prod=='a',]$id)

 (504970,508749.9] (508749.9,512499.8] (512499.8,516249.6] (516249.6,519999.5] (519999.5,523749.4] (523749.4,527499.2] (527499.2,531249.1]   (531249.1,535029] 
                  3                   1                   1                   0                   1                   2                   1                   2 

table(cut(db[db$prod=='a',]$count,8,digits=1,dig.lab = 7))

(304970,308749.9] (308749.9,312499.8] (312499.8,316249.6] (316249.6,319999.5] (319999.5,323749.4] (323749.4,327499.2] (327499.2,331249.1]   (331249.1,335029] 
                  3                   1                   1                   0                   1                   2                   1                   2
```

Comment: what is purpose of your `cut` function in above code?

Comment: I'm looking to generate ranges for each product. I need this for an actual data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to first convert group-wise output of `cut` to `character` and add a column. Now in the next statement convert new column (containing character) to `factor` without grouping on anything. In that way you will be able avoid groupwise factors coercing to same values.

You can try as:

```
library(data.table)

# Data
db<-data.table(count=c(331948, 334999, 321000, 305000, 324100, 310000, 305000, 
325000, 305000, 329999, 315000,531948, 534999, 521000, 505000, 524100,
510000, 505000, 525000, 505000, 529999, 515000),
prod=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b",
      "b","b","b","b","b","b"))

# Try this
db[, id := as.character(cut(count, 8, digits=1, dig.lab = 7)), by=.(prod)][
    ,id:=as.factor(id)]

# Result 
db
      count prod                  id
# 1: 331948    a   (331249.1,335029]
# 2: 334999    a   (331249.1,335029]
# 3: 321000    a (319999.5,323749.4]
# 4: 305000    a   (304970,308749.9]
# 5: 324100    a (323749.4,327499.2]
# 6: 310000    a (308749.9,312499.8]
# 7: 305000    a   (304970,308749.9]
# 8: 325000    a (323749.4,327499.2]
# 9: 305000    a   (304970,308749.9]
# 10: 329999    a (327499.2,331249.1]
# 11: 315000    a (312499.8,316249.6]
# 12: 531948    b   (531249.1,535029]
# 13: 534999    b   (531249.1,535029] 
# so on
```

Comment: It is not yet right, as the result for "B" is the same as that for "A".

Comment: @lolo Sorry. It was typo from me as I didn't copy the last answer from my RStudio. Have a look now.